# Start activity if not started only

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want a service that starts an activity if it has not started. If it is already started and visible.. nothing must be done. I am using the code below. My main activity has launchmode singleInstance

```
Intent activiy_intent = new Intent(c, MainActivity.class);
activiy_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(activiy_intent);
```

The problem with this code is that when my activity is already started and visible and i call this code in my service, the onResume() callback is called on my activity which is already visible .. as a result codes in the onResume callback are called (initialize lists, etc...)

Comment: I get this error

android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

It forces me to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: what is c in new Intent(c, MainActivity.class)?

Comment: instance of my service

Comment: for now I am using kind of a hack.

setting a static variable to indicate if my activity is visible or not (set to true onResume and false onPause).. my service starts the activity only if the variable is false... not sure if it is a good approach?

Comment: try to change launchmode to singletop.

Comment: nopes still no good.. my activity(already visible) pauses and resumes